# How to align values of a column right in a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I was trying to take the mean of rows, but when I ran the below, it gave me an error.

```
thetable = thetable %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate('2020rate'=mean(c_across(98:109)))

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `2020rate = mean(c_across(98:109))`.
i The error occurred in row 1.
Caused by error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't combine `Jan 2020` <double> and `Mar 2020` <character>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I looked at the row in question, and it turns out that the entire column is left aligned, while the rest of the data is right aligned.

data frame:

```
Jan2020  Feb2020  Mar2020  Apr2020
      5        3  2              2
      3        4  5              3
```

I saw a method to use gt(), but this turns it into an unreadable data frame. Is there another way to align all column values right?

Comment: As the error says you have some columns that are `character` class.  Convert the columns to numeric first before doing the `mean` ise. `thetable %>% mutate("2020rate" = rowMeans(across(98:109, as.numeric), na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: `gt()` is used for rendering data into nice-looking tables for reports, not for basic data munging, fixing, summarizing, etc.

Comment: @akrun ah! that did the trick. Is there a way to apply as.numeric to the entire data frame all at once so that I don't have to write this in every time? I tried this but it errored: thetable.1<−lapply(thetable,as.numeric)
Warning message:
In lapply(thetable, as.numeric) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: that warning is fine (not a error) because you have some values in columns that are not numeric and it returns NA